# Connect to sql server 2016 named instance without specifying Port number

Tags: sql-server

I have installed named instance of SQL Server 2016 and configured it to accept remote connections. I have added UDP port 1434 to the firewall (and I have turned off the firewall altogether). SQL Server Browser service is running and had been restarted a number of times as has the SQL Server service. TCP/IP and Named Pipes have been enabled in the configuration manager.

I can connect to the instance from my PC if I include the port number "server\instancename,portno" but cannot connect if I leave out the port number. I get the usual - "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server....." error. Its like SQL Server Browser is not running - but I can see that it is listening if I use netstat -a.

This is my first outing with SQL Server 2016 so maybe I am missing something but I cant find anything similar on the Web.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Rgds
John

Comment: SQL's default port is 1433. So if you don't specify your custom port, it'll try and connect on the default port and it won't work.

Comment: 1433 is used only for default instances. I am using a named instance so the port is dynamic which is where SQL Server Browser comes in. I did open port 1433 too anyway and it made no difference. I can try and assign 1433 as the static port for my named instance but I don't want to go this route as it is likely we will have another instance on this server in the coming weeks so will run into the same issue again.

Comment: when you launch a connection without a port, can you see traffic to port 1434 of your server, and a response coming back (e..g using wireshark or a similar tool)? That would help to show whether or not it's connecting to the SQL Server Browser service.

Comment: TBH though if you're planning to use this through a firewall in the end, you're going to run into problems, because you still need the actual port that the instance runs on to be open alongside port 1434. And if that's dynamically assigned, you're going to have trouble configuring the firewall. Microsoft recommends in this situation that you simply assign static ports to each named instance. See this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Comment: I don't have any software loaded to monitor traffic. I will look into that. I do have10 other servers/vms here running named instances and I only have SSMS and UDF port 1434 opened on the Firewall (not 1433 - and no problems connecting). This new server was set up in AWS which is outside of my control so am wondering if there are some configuration issues there that may be the problem.

Comment: can you explain the setup a little more clearly? Are your other 10 SQL servers internal? i.e. is there a firewall between you and them? Or is the firewall only between you and AWS? Also you say "no problems connecting" with only 1434 open. Do you mean no problems connecting to the other 10 servers, or no problems connecting to the AWS server (presumably when naming a port - which port, btw?)?. You also say "I only have SSMS and UDF port 1434 opened". Do you mean that a port is opened for SSMS to use? Or that ssms.exe is allowed to pass through the firewall on all ports as an exception?